# how to cp files with spaces in the filename when files are provided by find

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to ensure that all files found by find with a given criteria are properly copied to the required location.

```
$from = '/some/path/to/the/files'
$ext  = 'custom_file_extension'
$dest = '/new/destination/for/the/files/with/given/extension'

cp 'find $from -name "*.$ext"' $dest
```

The problem here is that, when a file found with the proper extension and it is containing space cp cannot copy it properly.

Comment: You don't do that. You can't splat filenames with spaces that way. You get to use something from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 to read the output from find line-by-line or into an array **or** you use `find -exec` to do the copy work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-exec`:

```
find "$from" -name "*.$ext" -exec cp {} "$dest" \;
```

Comment: Since the OP specifically mentioned spaces, you're missing quotes around `$from` and `$dest`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't do that. You can't splat filenames with spaces that way.

You either get to use something from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 to read the output from find line-by-line or into an array **or** you use `find -exec` to do the copy work.

Something like this:

```
from='/some/path/to/the/files'
ext='custom_file_extension'
dest='/new/destination/for/the/files/with/given/extension'

find "$from" -name "*.$ext" -exec cp -t "$dest" {} +
```

Using `-exec command +` here means that `find` will only execute as many `cp` commands as it needs based on command length limits. Using `-exec command ;` here would run one `cp`-per-file-found (but is more portable to older systems).

See comment from gniourf_gniourf about the use of `-t` in that `cp` command to make `-exec command +` work correctly.

Comment: This will not work with most versions of `find`: [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html): _Only a plus sign that follows an argument containing the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression. Other uses of the plus sign shall not be treated as special._ Even GNU `find` complains about this and doesn't accept the command. That's why some versions of `cp` have the `-t` (target directory) option: `find "$from" -name "*.$ext" -exec cp -t "$dest" {} +`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy file one by one:

```
for file in "$from"/*."$ext"; do
    cp "$file" "$dest"
done
```

I just use glob here, and it's enough and complete. I think `find` may introduce problem if the file name contains funny character.

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted? it's very correct (yet non-recursive—but it's not the kind of answer that deserves a downvote, really).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf never a reason for a downvoter. i am used to this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this sort of problem is `xargs -0` and the `-print0` flag for `find`.

`-print0` instructs find to print the results with a NUL character termination, instead of a newline, while `-0` for `xargs` tells it expect input in that format.

Finally, the -J option for xargs allows one to put the arguments in the right place for a copy.

```
find "$from" -name "*.$ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -J % cp % "$dest"
```

Comment: This just introduces an unnecessary `xargs` invocation without any real advantage over the other answers. `find -exec` can do all that with less code.

Comment: It runs `cp` only once (well, for up to 5000 files at a time, anyhow), and generalizes more easily to other cases.

Comment: It does avoid the "problems" of `-exec command ;` that's true (though that `5000` number isn't accurate) but I don't know that I agree that it generalizes better since doing multiple (or more complicated) commands with this gets more complicated than doing that with `find` directly since you can use more than one `-exec` easily.

Comment: Yup, 5000 is system dependent (but it's pretty large by default pretty much everywhere, as far as I'm aware). If your version of `find` supports `+` in `-exec`, then it's pretty much equivalent to using that. For multiple actions per item, then multiple `-exec` is indeed the way to go. On the other hand, `xargs` gives you much more control over how your command is going to be invoked, with options such as -p, -t and -s.

Comment: FYI: every POSIX `find` supports `-exec ... +`, but not all support `-print0`, same for `xargs -0`. So your solution is much less portable than other ones.

Comment: `-exec ... +` support came late to quite a few platforms. I only just now learnt that recent versions of OpenBSD support it (it came only in 2009 in version 4.6.) GNU findutils has had `-print0` since 1990 or so. More info here: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#xargs

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use -exec argument of find command to do this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext" -exec cp {} ./destination_dir \;
```

I've checked this case with files containing spaces and it's work for me. Also don't forger to point out '-type f' if you want to find only files, not directories.

Comment: How is that different from the other answers? You should also mention that using `;` at the end of `-exec` will spawn a `cp` for every file found, which can make a difference if you're copying a lot of files.

Comment: Daniel, the other answers appears when i was writing my answer. I've been needed a time to check my solution.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? it's actually very correct. It's amazing that there are lots of wrong answers on this site that get upvoted, and correct ones that get downvoted.